# Check arrays of dictionaries for key-value pair and update another list accordingly

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have multiple arrays containing dictionaries. I want to check these arrays and update another list as per the key-value pairs encountered while iterating the dictionaries within arrays.

So for following 4 sentiment arrays:

```
senti_array1 = [{'senti':'Positive', 'count':15}, {'senti':'Negative', 'count':10}, {'senti':'Neutral', 'count':5}]
senti_array2 = [{'senti':'Positive', 'count':8}, {'senti':'Negative', 'count':4}]
senti_array3 = [{'senti':'Positive', 'count':2}]
senti_array4 = [{'senti':'Negative', 'count':7}, {'senti':'Neutral', 'count':12}]

pos_list=[]
neg_list=[]
neu_list=[]
```

If their is a negative sentiment present the corresponding list (`neg_list`) in this case should be updated with its count value, else 0 should be appended in the list if 'Negative' sentiment is not present in the array.

The final output should be :

```
pos_list=[15, 8, 2, 0]
neg_list=[10, 4, 0, 7]
neu_list=[5, 0, 0, 12]
```

I have tried using normal for loops but I do not get the desired output because each time if else condition is checked a 0 is appended in the list if sentiment not present, which yields wrong output. I think maps or lambda functions can be used  for this but have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dict that maps sentiments to a dict mapping of array indices to counts, so that you can iterate through the 3 sentiments and iterate an index through the range of the number of arrays to build lists of counts. Use the `dict.get` method set the default count to 0:

```
mapping = {}
for i, l in enumerate((senti_array1, senti_array2, senti_array3, senti_array4)):
    for d in l:
        mapping.setdefault(d['senti'], {})[i] = d['count']
pos_list, neg_list, neu_list = ([mapping.get(s, {}).get(k, 0) for k in range(i + 1)] for s in ('Positive', 'Negative', 'Neutral'))
```

Given your sample input, `pos_list` becomes:

```
[15, 8, 2, 0]
```

`neg_list` becomes:

```
[10, 4, 0, 7]
```

and `neu_list` becomes:

```
[5, 0, 0, 12]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... And yes the expected output for `neu_list` was wrong in question, have corrected it now. Thanks.