# Efficient way to operate on two JSON lists and update them

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, optimization

I want to operate on python lists containing JSONs in such a way that the `key` value in `source_split_response` gets replaced by the `name` value of `online_source` wherever `onlineId` value equals to the `key` value in `source_split_response`.

```
online_source = [{'_id': {'$oid': '5c989c112ae8570ca8c6bcd1'},
  'name': 'Blogs',
  'onlineId': '606881',
  'type': 'source'},
 {'_id': {'$oid': '5c989c122ae8570ca8c6bcd2'},
  'name': 'Facebook',
  'onlineId': '606911',
  'type': 'source'},
 {'_id': {'$oid': '5c989c122ae8570ca8c6bcd3'},
  'name': 'Instagram',
  'onlineId': '606937',
  'type': 'source'},
 {'_id': {'$oid': '5c989c122ae8570ca8c6bcd4'},
  'name': 'Tumblr',
  'onlineId': '606961',
  'type': 'source'},
 {'_id': {'$oid': '5c989c122ae8570ca8c6bcd5'},
  'name': 'Twitter',
  'onlineId': '606963',
  'type': 'source'},
 {'_id': {'$oid': '5c989c132ae8570ca8c6bcd6'},
  'name': 'Others',
  'onlineId': '606949',
  'type': 'source'},
 {'_id': {'$oid': '5c989c132ae8570ca8c6bcd7'},
  'name': 'Forums',
  'onlineId': '606925',
  'type': 'source'},
 {'_id': {'$oid': '5c989c132ae8570ca8c6bcd8'},
  'name': 'Youtube',
  'onlineId': '606965',
  'type': 'source'}]


source_split_response = [
        {
            "key" : "News", 
            "doc_count" : 20
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "606881",
            "doc_count" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "606925", 
            "doc_count" : 6
        }
    ]
```

Python code:

```
for ind_source_resp in range(0, len(source_split_response)):
    for ind_source_map in range(0, len(online_source)):
        if(source_split_response[ind_source_resp]['key'] == online_source[ind_source_map]['onlineId']):
            source_split_response[ind_source_resp]['key'] = online_source[ind_source_map]['name']
print(source_split_response)
```

Prints: `[{'key': 'News', 'doc_count': 20}, {'key': 'Blogs', 'doc_count': 12}, {'key': 'Forums', 'doc_count': 6}]`

Expected Output: `[{'key': 'News', 'doc_count': 20}, {'key': 'Blogs', 'doc_count': 12}, {'key': 'Forums', 'doc_count': 6}]`

> Although I get the final output as the desired one, but is their a
>   more efficient and pythonic way to achieve the same?

Comment: question: is the onlineId always the same ? for example  `'name': 'Youtube', 'onlineId': '606965'`

Comment: @Fabian yes it will be same always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the mapping of ids to names in a dictionaty to avoid iterating whole array to match them:

```
idDict = dict()

for entry in online_source:
    idDict[entry['onlineId']] = entry['name']

for entry in source_split_response:
    if entry['key'] in idDict:
        entry['key'] = idDict[entry['key']]

print(source_split_response)
```

I don´t know why you want list comprehension but here is a way:

```
idDict = {entry['onlineId']:entry['name'] for entry in online_source}

[entry.update({'key': idDict.get(entry['key'], entry['key'])}) for entry in source_split_response]

print(source_split_response)
```

Comment: thanks... seems more efficient.. but can we use list comprehensions or iterators for this? something like done in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54969923/9592759

Comment: @AshuGrover added

Comment: perfect... thanks... I wanted this kind of way because i want to learn minimalist coding approaches and ways which are more pythonic.